# How can AbstractMap.SimpleEntry be mutable?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

How can [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) be simultaneously

1) mutable (it's method `setValue(`) changes value part of the entry)

2) having `equals()`/`hashCode()` defined including value part of the entry

3) be the part of `Set<Map.Entry<T,K>> entrySet()` result

It seems to me, that these three points are controversial. For example, first two violates contract of `Set<>` interface, which is not recommending to have mutable elements of the set.

May I be sure, that mutating of `Value` won't break the map?

Why didn't they did `Entry` comparable and hashable by key only? This would increase speed in some cases?

Comment: This is Java... "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity"

Comment: Isn't it the key that needs to have the property? Why are you asking about breaking the `Map` in the `Set`?

Answer (score 5):

> I be sure, that mutating of Value won't break the map?

Yes, absolutely. The `HashMap` buckets take into account only the key portion of the entry:

```
public V  [More ...] put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode()); // <<== HERE
    ...
}
```

> Why didn't they did Entry comparable and hashable by key only? This would increase speed in some cases?

The `hashCode` and `equals` of `Map.Entry` have very little relevance: they would be used only if you wanted to hash entries *outside* the `HashMap` itself. The internal implementation of the `EntrySet` supplied to the callers of `Map.entrySet` does not use `hashCode` / `equals` of the entry - instead, they use the hash code of only the key portion. Here is part of a relevant source code for looking up an object in the entry set:

```
 public boolean contains(Object o) {
     if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
         return false;
     Map.Entry<K,V> e = (Map.Entry<K,V>) o;
     Entry<K,V> candidate = getEntry(e.getKey());
     return candidate != null && candidate.equals(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction here. The main point that you seem to have missed is that `entrySet()` **does not support adding elements to it**.

As such, if a set is well-formed when it is returned by the map, you

1. Cannot create a duplicate in the set, as you cannot change keys or add new entries, hence any two entries will remain different
2. **Can** change the hash code of an `Entry`, but **cannot** influence the hash code of the key, so HashMaps will not break - the bucket of the entry is still the same
3. Cannot change the position of the `Entry` in a sorted map.

In fact: `setValue()` does not allow you to change ANYTHING about how the entry is handled by the map, and hence all map contracts will be preserved.

I cannot attest why exactly `equals()` and `hashCode()` were implemented in this specific way, maybe the authors of Java had a use case in mind, I don't. (Then again I don't have any use case for those methods in mind at all)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an "opinion" question.  Here's my best guess.

I think that `Set<Map.Entry<T,K>>` is made available so that you can iterate over the elements of the set to get all key/value pairs in a map.  However, other operations on this `Set` would be used rarely.  In particular, it seems unlikely that one would use the `contains` method on this set, which would require building a `Map.Entry` object of some concrete class that has both a key *and* a value, to see if it's in this `Set<Map.Entry<T,K>>`.  Since I think `contains` would be the main use of the `hashCode`, and since `contains` would rarely be used, I don't think the `hashCode()` defined for the `Map.Entry` is of much use, and thus it shouldn't be a cause for concern.  `hashCode()` is, of course, present because all `Object`s have them; why they felt a need to define its value formally, I don't know.  But I think it's harmless.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry is to be considered a private implementation detail (its not even used by all Map implementations, e.g. HashMap doesn't use it).

Note that there is *no API* that exposes this type directly - its arguable that this class could have been made protected or package private instead of public.

The defining public API is Map.Entry (note that any Map returns a Set). Any implementation of Entry needs to conform to this contract, and the hashCode implementation is clearly defined there.

A class making use of SimpleEntry will need to override part of the definition to handle setValue() *if* that is needed by its entrySet() implementation (Take a look at HashMap for an example how its handled). The hashCode of Entry, while documented, is *not neccessarily used* by the implementation of entrySet().

As for "why" is it the way it is: Ask the designer. Conjecture on my part is that there isn't a deeper reason.